# how to pipe commands in ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu

How do I pipe commands and their results in Ubuntu when writing them in the terminal. I would write the following commands in sequence -

```
$ ls | grep ab
abc.pdf
cde.pdf
$ cp abc.pdf cde.pdf files/
```

I would like to pipe the results of the first command into the second command, and write them all in the same line. How do I do that ?

something like

```
$ cp "ls | grep ab" files/
```

(the above is a contrived example and can be written as `cp *.pdf files/`)

Comment: `cp \`ls | grep ab\` files/` -- notice the surrounding backticks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use xargs, you need to ensure that the filename arguments are the last arguments passed to the cp command. You can accomplish this with the `-t` option to cp to specify the target directory:

```
ls | grep ab | xargs cp -t files/
```

Of course, even though this is a contrived example, you [should not parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Except of course this doesn't handle files with spaces (easy to fix) or control characters (easy to fix) or returns (hard to fix) in it.  However, I didn't know about -t so you get the upvote.

Comment: Right, depending what actually comes in the pipeline before xargs. Using GNU tools, `find ... -print0 | xargs -0` can take care of filenames with whitespace

Comment: Exactly so, but your solution didn't offer this. My suggestion of using xargs, three hours before yours, did.

Answer (score 6):

Use the following:

```
cp `ls | grep ab` files/
```

Comment: Good solution, as long as the number of matching files is decently controlled.  The maximum size of a command line is pretty large now-a-days, but isn't infinite.  Still, for most practical uses it is just fine.

Answer (score 6):

Well, since the xargs person gave up, I'll offer my xargs solution:

```
ls | grep ab | xargs echo | while read f; do cp $f files/; done
```

Of course, this solution suffers from an obvious flaw: files with spaces in them will cause chaos.

An xargs solution without this flaw?  Hmm...

```
ls | grep ab | xargs '-d\n' bash -c 'docp() { cp "$@" files/; }; docp "$@"'
```

Seems a bit klunky, but it works.  Unless you have files with returns in them I mean.  However, anyone who does that deserves what they get.  Even that is solvable:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*ab*' -print0 | xargs -0 bash -c 'docp() { cp "$@" files/; }; docp "$@"'
```

Comment: `xargs echo` is ... interesting. It may as well be omitted from the pipeline.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Not at all.  It forces multiple arguments to be on the same input line.  Compare:  `ls | xargs echo | wc -l` vs `ls | wc -l`.  Assuming you have multiple files in your directory of course.

Comment: The xargs does force more output onto a single line, so that fewer instances of cp are executed, but it does not change the result.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Of course.  That's the whole point.  Added efficiency without drawbacks is nothing to be sneezed at.

Comment: There is a drawback.  With `xargs`, nothing is done until ls outputs enough names that xargs is able to collect enough arguments to force an instance of cp to be executed.  That's a waste of time and memory, with no benefit.  The actions here are not CPU bound, and the time to spawn `cp` is (probably) insignificant compared to the execution of each `cp`.

Comment: Are you serious?  1) With a pipeline the pipe buffering is going to cause delays anyway.  2) Overall execution time matters: you are not going to proceed until all files are copied anyway, 3) The overhead of cp for normal sized files (<2M on my system) is greater that the time taken to copy the files, meaning that xargs is a major win.

Comment: No, I wasn't being serious: I thought there would be very little difference in execution time.  Some rough benchmarks show that using xargs to do a single invocation of `cp` is indeed a significant win.  Nice technique.